NTP sever doesn't use reference clock after upgrade to 24.04.01 LTS
I have had a machine configured as a stratum 0 NTP server that has been running for years.
There is a serial attached box that contains a GNSS receiver and a disciplined, temperature controlled oscillator that keeps NTP accurate to within about 10 nanoseconds.
Before upgrading to 24.04.1 ntpq -p would typically show something like:
oNMEA(0)         .PPS.            0 l    7   16  377   0.0000 -0.0067   0.0012
After upgrading it shows  something like:
xNMEA(0)         .PPS.            0 l    8   16  377   0.0000 -95.6438   0.3890
Where the x at the beginning of the line indicates the reference clock is being rejected.
Yes, the attached box is still working and all the special files are there.
Does anyone have a clue what to do next other than to go back to 22.04.4 LTS?
Updated:
It seems that in 24.04.01 replaces the legacy ntp package with ntpsec, which in itself isn't a big deal.
However, from what I have found in syslog entries ppsapi is not implemented in the kernal, which makes Ubuntu useless for those using a precision attached reference clock.
From syslog:
ntpd[2609]: REFCLOCK: refclock_params: kernel PLL (hardpps, RFC 1589) not implemented
ntpd[2609]: REFCLOCK: NMEA(0) set PPSAPI params fails

Hi, I'm not entirely sure about your case, hence not posted as answer. But ntp(d) has been less and less maintained for a while and focus been more on chrony as a ntp-server. Maybe worth exploring the same setup, but with this SW stack https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/how-to-serve-the-network-time-protocol-with-chrony. It worked to feed in my gps device, although it was not as advanced as yours. But in general I've learned to love chrony>ntpd and it is worth trying for sure.
